# Cannot Read USB Printer status Except Printing and Idle status using C# WMI library

Tags: c#, wmi-query

I am developing application for Reading All Printer Status(USB Printer), I am using C# WMI library to read the printer status but I am getting only the Printing and Idle Status from that.

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}'", printerName);
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query);
ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
{
     foreach (PropertyData property in printer.Properties)
     {
         strMsg = " Name = " + ((property.Name != null) ? property.Name : " NULL") +   " Value = " + ((property.Value != null) ? property.Value.ToString() : " NULL");

         sw.WriteLine(strMsg);
     }
}
```

Above code, the one I am using for the same.

Help me to get rid from this.

Comment: Which property are you trying to read?

Comment: I am tying for all USB printer Status like No paper, Paper Jam, INK Low etc..  but i am only getting the printing status and idle.                                                                        also  How do i confirm that Printer(HP) driver is not updating the Winspool.drv?

Comment: "Paper Jam" and "Toner Low" are possible values of the `DetectedErrorState` property. Note though that vendors are not _obliged_ to fully implement WMI classes, sometimes the values are just not available.

Comment: After googled about the same, finally came to know that the USB Printer(Hp) driver is not updating the status into the Winspool.drv except Printing and idle status. so WMI could not get the other status.

Comment: Also , But the HP printer application reading the all status from the HpPrinter.. So Is there any way to findout the code/solution from that?

Comment: anybody knows the answer for the above questions

Comment: At last found the solution and My application can able to catch all Printer status .